# Python Tkinter - moving text when pressing a button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am writing a program in Python where the aim is to change background colors using the radio buttons, and where it should be possible to move the text "welcome to the left og right when pressing the buttons btLeft or btRight (10 pixels per click). I`m having a hard time making the moving of the text work, and it seems I am stuck. Can anybody please help? I am very new to Python, so sorry for my bad code...

```
from tkinter import * # Import tkinter

class Buttons:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() # Create a window
        window.title("Radio Buttons and Buttons")
        frame1 = Frame(window) # Create and add a frame to window
        frame1.pack() 
        self.v1 = IntVar()
        rbRed = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "Red", variable = self.v1, value=1, command = self.processRb) 
        rbYellow = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "Yellow", variable = self.v1, value=2, command = self.processRb) 
        rbWhite = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "White", variable = self.v1, value=3, command = self.processRb) 
        rbGrey = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "Grey", variable = self.v1, value=4, command = self.processRb) 
        rbGreen = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "green", variable = self.v1, value=5, command = self.processRb) 

        rbRed.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        rbYellow.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        rbWhite.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        rbGrey.grid(row = 1, column = 4)
        rbGreen.grid(row = 1, column = 5)

        frame2 = Frame(window, bg = "blue")
        frame2.pack() 
        self.canvas = Canvas(window)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.lbl1 = Label(self.canvas, text = "Welcome").place(x = 100, y = 50) 

        frame3 = Frame(window) # Create and add a frame to window
        frame3.pack() 
        btLeft = Button(frame3, text = "<=", command = self.processbtLeft)
        btRight = Button(frame3, text = "=>", command = self.processbtRight)
        btLeft.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        btRight.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        
        window.mainloop() # Create an event loop
    
    def processbtLeft(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.lbl1, -10, 0)  
        self.canvas.update()
    def processbtRight(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.lbl1, 10, 0)  
        self.canvas.update()

    def processRb(self):
        if self.v1.get() == 1:
            self.canvas["bg"] = "red"
        elif self.v1.get() == 2:
            self.canvas["bg"] = "yellow"
        elif self.v1.get() == 3:
            self.canvas["bg"] = "white"
        elif self.v1.get() == 4:
            self.canvas["bg"] = "grey"
        elif self.v1.get() == 5:
            self.canvas["bg"] = "green"
    
        
Buttons() #
```

Comment: You can't move a label using `move()` if it is put in the canvas by `place()`.  Also `self.lbl1` is None.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you create a `Label` and place it on the canvas, but then treat it as if it was an *element* of the canvas; that is, created by it. `self.canvas.move()` can only control things that were created by the canvas. If you want to create a label that can be controlled by the canvas, you need to use `self.canvas.create_text(...)`.

In your code, that means that you should replace

```py
self.lbl1 = Label(self.canvas, text = "Welcome").place(x = 100, y = 50)
```

with

```py
self.lbl1 = self.canvas.create_text(100, 50, text="Weclome")
```

This should fix the problem.

Another general `tkinter` tip: I notice that when you create your label, you assign `self.lbl1` to the return value of `.place(x=100, y=50)`. This causes errors when you try to reference the variable later; you will see the notorious `NoneType object has no attribute` error that's all over Stack Overflow. Instead of calling `.place()` when you create the label, you should call it *after* creating the label:

```py
self.lbl1 = Label(self.canvas, text = "Welcome")
self.lb1.place(x=100, y=100)
```

Whenever you create a widget, you should call `place()`, `pack()`, and `grid()` *after* creating the widget.